# React/Redux - Do I store mapped values of Redux items in Redux or Component state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an app whereby users list transactions made within a calendar month. These transactions are stored in a Redux store. I need to map over these to display an accumulated value for all the transactions, but I am not sure whether this needs to be stored in Redux, or in React component state?

I am thinking this could just be React component state, but as I am learning React/Redux, I'm not to sure.

Thanks

Comment: Use component state where you can. As soon as you have distant components that now require each other's data, then a centralized data store via `redux` will be beneficial. Basically, I'd suggest only adding in Redux until you find yourself in that scenario.

Comment: @lux, you mean: "I'd suggest only adding in component state until you find yourself in that scenario", right?

Comment: @DamienLeroux Nope, I mean keeping state as local as possible at the component level. If you need shared data, implement Redux. Or if you prefer, from the author or react-router: https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/721049232996630528

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As accumulated value will  change as more transactions are added, you should recalculate it on each store update and as updating stores should re-render your component, you should probably calculate it in render function of your component.

Check out [Best Practices for Component State in React.js](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/03/24/best-practices-for-component-state-in-reactjs.html)